# wordpress output the content of a static home page instead of all available posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently writing my first wordpress design and have some problems with the start page.

I want a static page to be the homepage. For this i made some changes to the page.php file to restructure it for the "home" page.

However when the specific page is set as start page the function

```
the_post()
```

Seems to output different results than when it's not the home page.

Used code:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' ); 
endwhile;
```

This part of the code loops through my poosts instead of outputting the content of my current static page - which I actually want. It somehow works when the page is not the home / start page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to roll back to the original page.php, and copy the content of it into a new file named front-page.php. If present this file will always be used to display the front page. Then it's just a matter of doing all the needed modifications to this file.

As a side note; your code is working on all other pages because they are static by default.

There are also several other ways to go about this. Read more here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page